# javascript function is not working in cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cordova, phonegap

In cordova i want to call a button event from the listener. In my app i am loading a page http://example.org/app . In that page have a button it's class name is btn. I want show an alert when that button click. The html code of web page is shown below. 
`<p><a class="btn">Click</a></p>`

The cordova code in index.js

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);        
    },
    onDeviceReady: function () {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    // Here, we redirect to the web site.
    var targetUrl = "http://example.org/app";
    var bkpLink = document.getElementById("bkpLink");
    bkpLink.setAttribute("href", targetUrl);
    bkpLink.text = targetUrl;
    window.location.replace(targetUrl);
    //I want to call a alert when button click      
    document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
    return function() {
        alert("okkkkkkkkkk");
    };
    })(i), false);  

    },
    // Note: This code is taken from the Cordova CLI template.
    receivedEvent: function (id) {
    }

};
app.initialize();
```

When i am using this code it is not working.
How to listen the click event of loaded web page. Please help me.

Comment: Have you define the `i` variable used to call the function in click event ?

Comment: No i didn't define the i variable.

Comment: if you want to do in jquery a simply function will do , $('.btn').click(function(){
alert('okkkk')});

Comment: Is it work in cordova?

Comment: Try to define it or remove it, also you can just make `addEventListener('click', function() { alert('ok'); })`

Comment: It also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this . I made changes to function that will will execute on click.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);        
    },
    onDeviceReady: function () {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    // Here, we redirect to the web site.
    var targetUrl = "http://example.org/app";
    var bkpLink = document.getElementById("bkpLink");
    bkpLink.setAttribute("href", targetUrl);
    bkpLink.text = targetUrl;
    window.location.replace(targetUrl);
    //I want to call a alert when button click      
    document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].addEventListener('click', function(i) {
        alert("okkkkkkkkkk");
    }, false);  

    },
    // Note: This code is taken from the Cordova CLI template.
    receivedEvent: function (id) {
    }

};
app.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the external site in the app. So you have to write the click function in the external site not inside your app.

The code after `window.location.replace(targetUrl);` will not work.

Comment: I am loading external site but we can call the click function. I got the code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/run-web-app-in-cordova . Please see Add Camera Functionality to the Cordova Apps

Comment: The code after window.location.replace(targetUrl); will not work. Inorder to make it work you need to write the click function in your external site.

Comment: Wis did u check the above link. I think it is possible. In that reference site they are calling external web page.

Comment: I have removed the window.location.replace(targetUrl); . After that also not working.